# how to recognize "(x,y)" from the text

Tags: c#

I'm trying to search for "(x,y)" pair from the text and convert the values of 'x' and 'y' to double. I did this class

```
class Grammer
{
    private List<String> collection;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public Grammer()
    {
        collection = new List<String>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="line"></param>
    public Grammer(String line)
    {
        collection = new List<String>();
        lineReader(line);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="line"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool checkSyntax(String line)
    {
        bool des = true;
        String temp = "";
        String temp2 = "";
        String number = "";
        double Xvalue = 0.0;
        double Yvalue = 0.0;


        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {

            if (line[i] == '(')
            {
                temp += line[i];
                for (int j = i + 1; j < line.Length; j++)
                {
                    temp += line[j];
                    if (line[j] == ',')
                    {
                        if (searchDuplication(temp))
                        {
                            for (int k = 1; k < temp.Length - 1; k++)
                            {
                                number += temp[k];
                            }

                            if (isNumber(number))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Xvalue = Convert.ToDouble(number);
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("unexpected error: Xvalue can not be ' {0} ' \n\n " +
                                    "' {0} ' can not be converted to double ", number);
                                    des = false;
                                }
                                number = "";

                                for (int t = j + 1; t < line.Length; t++)
                                {
                                    temp += line[t];
                                    if (line[t] == ')')
                                    {
                                        j = t;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (searchDuplication(temp))
                                {
                                    for (int g = 0; g < temp.Length; g++)
                                    {
                                        if (temp[g] == ',')
                                        {
                                            temp2 += temp[g];
                                            for (int r = g + 1; r < temp.Length; r++)
                                            {
                                                temp2 += temp[r];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    for (int p = 1; p < temp2.Length - 1; p++)
                                    {
                                        number += temp2[p];
                                    }

                                    ////
                                    if (searchDuplication(temp2))
                                    {

                                        if (isNumber(number))
                                        {
                                            try
                                            {
                                                Yvalue = Convert.ToDouble(number);
                                            }
                                            catch (Exception)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine("unexpected error: Yvalue can not be ' {0} ' \n\n " +
                                                "' {0} ' can not be converted to double ", number);
                                                des = false;
                                            } //Console.WriteLine("test line temp2 == {0}", temp2);
                                            number = "";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            i = j + 1;
                                            des = false;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        i = j + 1;
                                        des = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i = j + 1;
                                    des = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                i = j + 1;
                                des = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            i = j + 1;
                            des = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }// if line[j] = ,
                } // for loop j
            }
        }

        return des;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pair"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private String checkPreparation(String line)
    {
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i] != ' ')
            {
                temp += line[i];
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="line"></param>
    private void lineReader(String line)
    {
        String temp = "";
        line = checkPreparation(line);

        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i] == '(')
            {
                for (int j = i; j < line.Length; j++)
                {
                    temp += line[j];
                    if (line[j] == ')')
                    {
                        i = j + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(searchDuplication(temp))
            {
                if (checkSyntax(temp))
                {
                    collection.Add(temp);
                }
            }
            temp = "";
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pair"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool searchDuplication(String pair)
    {
        bool des = false;
        int op = 0;
        int cm = 0;
        int cp = 0;

        if (pair != null && pair != "")
        {
            //
            if (pair[0] == '(' && pair[pair.Length - 1] == ',')
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < pair.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (pair[i] == '(')
                    {
                        op++;
                    }

                    if (pair[i] == ',')
                    {
                        cm++;
                    }

                    if (pair[i] == ')')
                    {
                        cp++;
                    }

                    if (op == 0 && cm == 0 && cp == 0)
                    {
                        des = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        des = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (pair[0] == ',' && pair[pair.Length - 1] == ')')
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < pair.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (pair[i] == '(')
                    {
                        op++;
                    }

                    if (pair[i] == ',')
                    {
                        cm++;
                    }

                    if (pair[i] == ')')
                    {
                        cp++;
                    }

                    if (op == 0 && cm == 0 && cp == 0)
                    {
                        des = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        des = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (pair[0] == '(' && pair[pair.Length - 1] == ')')
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < pair.Length - 1; i++)
                {

                    if (pair[i] == '(')
                    {
                        op++;
                    }

                    if (pair[i] == ',')
                    {
                        cm++;
                    }

                    if (pair[i] == ')')
                    {
                        cp++;
                    }

                    if (op == 0 && cm == 1 && cp == 0)
                    {
                        des = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        des = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            des = false;
        }
        return des;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="degite"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool isDegite(Char degite)
    {
        Char[] D = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.' };
        bool des = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < D.Length; i++)
        {
            if (degite == D[i])
            {
                des = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return des;
    }

    private bool isNumber(String number)
    {
        bool des = false;
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
        {
            if (isDegite(number[i]))
            {
                des = true;

                if (number[i] == '.')
                {
                    j++;
                }

                if (j > 1)
                {
                    des = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return des;
    }

    public List<String> getCollection()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!checkSyntax(collection[i]) && collection[i] == null && collection[i].ToString() == "")
            {
                collection.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }



        return collection;
    }

}
```

However I'm not happy with result as well as the code quality.

I think it does very heavy process, it also wouldn't recognize some of the pair, for example, "(,)((5,5)"

Comment: Step through the code and see where it goes off the rails.

Comment: Oh, wow. Those `else`s killed me a little inside. Point of note though. You might mean `Grammar` rather than `Grammer` as class name.

Comment: Learn how to write a lexer instead. I have no idea what your text input be and your rule for other texts not in the expected format.

Comment: I don't have special text at moment but, I generate random chars then I send it to the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for regular expressions

```
    string text = "aldkjf;la(100,200)a;slknl;knw(400,400)";
    string pattern = @"\(\d+,\d+\)";

    var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

    foreach(Match match in matches)
    {
        var numberMatches = Regex.Matches(match.Value, @"\d+");

        double x = double.Parse(numberMatches[0].Value);
        double y = double.Parse(numberMatches[1].Value);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", x, y);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be clearly a case where a `Regex` is called for.

This should do the trick:  `"\((\d+),(\d+)\)"`

UPDATE (again)  Full code this time (after Sam I am, but mine doesn't need multiple searches)

```
var searchText = "(,)((2,3) (4,5)";
var regex = new Regex(@"\((\d+),(\d+)\)");
var matches = regex.Matches(searchText);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    var x = double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    var y = double.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}/{1}]", x,y);

}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, IMO.

Comment: This is similar to the link only answers, except it doesn't even have a link

Comment: Sorry -- I had to actually test the Regex pattern before posting it.